# Programmatically setting a customers website id

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, create

Could someone please advise why when adding a customer via an external script the website and store values are ignored and the customer is always assigned to "admin" and not to "main website".

I only have 1 website and 1 store within my Magento instance and each has an id of 1

My code is below:

```
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer   ->setWebsiteId(1)
                ->setStore(1)
                ->setFirstname('John')
                ->setLastname('Smith')
                ->setEmail('john@smith.com')
                ->setPassword('password')
                ->setGroupId('1');
    try{
        $customer->save();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setStore()` you could have use `setStoreId()`

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');

$email = 'john@smith.com';
$storeId = 1;

$website_id = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId)->getWebsiteId();
$customer->setWebsiteId($website_id);
$customer->setStoreId($storeId);
...
```

Comment: Unsure why, but even with correct customer model and storeId, this isn't working. I agree this does look correct and I would expect this to work, but at least in my case it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error with your code,

```
->setStore()
```

The above doesn't take an integer value for the store ID, it takes an instance of the current store, eg.

```
->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
```

In your case, I imagine it would be,

```
->setStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(2));
```